# Mudar palavra ao clicar na mesma palavra. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Oi, dei uma procurada em alguns scripts, porém não consegui achar nenhum que faça o que estou precisando, não achei nem no W3School.

Porém parece ser bem simples, clicar em uma palavra e ela mudar para outra palavra e ao clicar novamente mudar para o formato original.
 Por exemplo, Palavra1 ao clicar vira Palavra2 e ao clicar em Palavra2 vira Palavra1, nesse loop ai rsrs.

```
<a href="#palavra" id="palavra" onclick='document.getElementById("palavra").innerHTML = "Palavra2"'>Palavra1</a>
```

Este exemplo ele só muda uma vez...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso seja apenas para resolver essa situação você pode fazer utilizando [operador ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional).  Segue código:

```
<a href="#palavra" id="palavra" onclick='document.getElementById("palavra").innerHTML=(document.getElementById("palavra").innerHTML == "Palavra1") ? "Palavra2" : "Palavra1";'>Palavra1</a>
```

> ***Sintaxe:***
>
> condition ? expr1 : expr2
>
> ***Parâmetros:***
>
> **condition** - Uma expressão que é avaliada como true ou false.
>
> **expr1, expr2** - Expressões com valores de qualquer tipo.

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela ajuda! Sou novo aqui na comunidade. Desculpe qualquer coisa.

Comment: @GabrielRamos conte conosco. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa de `id`. Use o `this` que referencia o próprio elemento. E como nosso amigo disse na resposta dele, você pode usar o operador ternário:

```html
<a href="#palavra" onclick='var t = this.textContent; this.textContent = t == "Palavra1" ? "Palavra2" : "Palavra1"'>Palavra1</a>
```

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela ajuda! Sou novo aqui na comunidade. Desculpe qualquer coisa.

Comment: Bem-vindo amigo!

Answer (score 2):

No seu HTML coloca uma chamada para a função javascript.

```
< p onclick='MudaPalavra()' > Palavra1</p>
```

Após, no topo dentro da ta head ou no final do arquivo arquivo antes de fechar o , adicione as tags de script.

```
<script>
    function MudaPalavra(){
        if(document.getElementById("palavra").value == "Palavra1")
            document.getElementById("palavra").innerHTML = "Palavra2";
        else
            document.getElementById("palavra").innerHTML = "Palavra1";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela ajuda! Sou novo aqui na comunidade. Desculpe qualquer coisa.

Comment: Tranquilo Gabriel! Espero ter ajudado.Vai postando, tuas dúvidas, não tenha receio de pedir ajuda, só assim que tu conseguirá se desenvolver. Sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="texto" onclick="mudarPalavra()">Palavra1</p>

<script>
var palavra = false;

function mudarPalavra(){
    if (palavra == false) {
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Palavra1";    
        palavra = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = "Palavra2";    
        palavra = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oi, obrigado pela ajuda! Sou novo aqui na comunidade. Desculpe qualquer coisa.